# What is this large "payloadv2" file doing in mac os Install Data?

Tags: security, virus, anti-virus

This 10.5 gb folder titled "payloadv2" located in "mac os Install Data" has me concerned. It contains many archive split files. A quick google search only brought up a single result where it was believed to be a virus. Can anyone verify this?

Here's the pathname:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/macOS Install Data/UpdateBundle/AssetData/payloadv2
```

Comment: Is that folder inside an installer? If so that is normal. If not that is odd as the folder is *used as a source* by the installer to install components.

Comment: It's located in "macOS Install Data" as you can see in the pathname I posted above. Not sure if that qualities as an installer.

Comment: `payloadv2` is in iOS system updates. It wouldn't surprise me if its in macOS system updates these days too, especially considering where it's located. Have you recently run a system update, or is there one ready to install?

Comment: That's comforting to hear. The folder was created a couple months ago, so I can't recall what I was doing then.